# Which lego set is this shuttle from?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I found this shuttle in my old LEGO box. I tried to find the instruction but couldn't. Do you know which set this is from?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is from set [7151 Sith Infiltrator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7151-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the first wave of Starwars sets from 1999.

[image]

It is the only set that contains Windscreen 3x6x5 Bubble with that cockpit pattern, as visible on this picture:

[image]

Comment: Wow your right thank you. I have the long Part also partly together but didn't think it is one ship. No wonder I didn't find anything by searching for Tie Fighter xD